# Copying an old private key (from 2011) into Electrum: any risks?

Tags: wallet-recovery, bitcoin-wallet-app, recover-private-key

I have an old phone, with a version of the Bitcoin wallet from 2011.  It has a few satoshis in it, which are now worth enough to be worth recovering.  However, the phone can't connect to the Internet.

This version of the wallet apparently [stores the private key in an unencrypted base58 file](http://gary-rowe.com/agilestack/2011/12/28/how-to-recover-lost-bitcoins-from-an-android-wallet/), which I think is therefore equivalent to the [Wallet Import Format](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key#Base58_Wallet_Import_format).  I have root access, so I can view any file on the system, so getting it out isn't a problem.

Would there be any risks involved in simply copying the private key into Electrum 3.0 [using these instructions](https://bitcoinelectrum.com/importing-your-private-keys-into-electrum/) and then sending the contents to a more modern wallet?

From my understanding, the private key gives full access to the contents of the address, but a friend told me that given the key's age, I'd need to import it into bitcoin-qt and do a full sync in order to make sure that the address works properly.

Answer (score 1):

No, Bitcoin Core (formerly known as Bitcoin-QT) is not a wallet, it is a full node software + wallet, so there are better software to use as a wallet. Sure, you can use Bitcoin Core, but you'll need to keep your Bitcoin Core connected to the internet **for days** to synchronize.

To summarize, you should use a wallet software (sure, Electrum!) to import (or sweep the funds of) the private key.

Note: A few satoshis is worthless. The median transaction fee is currently **110,740 satoshis.** according to [this](https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/).

Comment: Thanks!  When I said a few satoshis, it's about 0.01 BTC so still worth something, I think.